# When to implement javascript MVC framework

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, model-view-controller

I work at a small web agency that specializes in web applications for startups. I am pushing my boss to put more resources into building robust frameworks on the client side using javascript mvc standards (I'm using [BackboneJS](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/)) and templating (using [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/))

I'm realizing that there are some situations where robust javascript frameworks make sense (eg. complex one-page web applications), and others where it may not be worth the effort (a list of blog posts, which can be templated using php)

We are trying to develop a standard for **when to implement a javascript framework on a page**, and when to rely on php for templating and server requests.

I am hoping some folks on the interwebs community have some thoughts on this matter, or could reference me to articles on this topic. I have some ideas of my own, but an "expert opinion" would hold more sway with my management team...

Comment: I think you have already answered your question.  Use them when you need them, and don't when you don't.

Comment: Ha, that's what I told my boss. What I'm really looking for is a bit of borrowed credibility in the form of thought by people with more experience than myself ;) Or at least some opposing view-points that I can weigh against each other. Come on, interweb! Give me some long-winded rants that I can use!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take into consideration who the end users are.
For Slower Devices (Office Desktops, 3 Year old Laptops etc.) a huge Clientside Framework can cause lacks and it might end up not being much fun to surf the page.

So if the website focuses on older people, non techies or office workers, you might want to take it easy on the javascript.

Comment: I'm not as much worried about speed as I am about use of developer hours. The cost of a few kbs of minified javascript is more than made up for by the increase of perceived speed allowed for by moving state to the client side.

Comment: I didn't mean speed loss due to the js overhead that has to be downloaded but rather the excecution speed on the clients PC when a client is weak (low RAM, low CPU) and has to execute lots of framework scripts.
If you want fast development i guess you'll not spend ages optimizing javascript and jquery code snipplets, doing intense performance testing on various machines right?

Comment: @KristianRafteseth Consider accepting my Answer or ask for further Detail. This will prevent this Question from getting any more Attention and also show at least some appreciation for the people who took the time to help you.